# Chaining mongoose promises in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, es6-promise

I have an api that creates a new document in mongodb using this function:

```
export function create(req, res) {
  return Track.create(req.body)
    .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

This just adds a new document, I would like to extend this and after the document was added I would like to add some more documents into another collection with the information from the response, something like this:

```
export function create2(info) {
  var trackId = info._id;
  var users = info.users;

  var basic = {
    trackId : trackId
  };

  for (let user of users) {
    basic.username = user.username;

    Location.create(basic);
  }
}
```

I would like to call the create2 function on a .then of the promise from the first create function something like this:

```
export function create(req, res) {
  return Track.create(req.body)
    .then(create2)
    .then(respondWithResult(res, 201))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

The problem is that create2 does not return a promise and I don't really know how to chain the promises returned by Location.create in create2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to make `create2` return a promise is with [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which is fulfilled when the array of promises passed to it are all fulfilled.  Something like this...

```
var _ = require('underscore');   // optional but useful for a better loop with '.map'

export function create2(info) {
  var trackId = info._id;
  var users = info.users;

  var basic = {
    trackId : trackId
  };

  var promises = _.map(users, function(user) {
    basic.username = user.username;
    return Location.create(basic);
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Comment: I pushed all the promises into an array and used this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/q to merge them with Q.all(arrayOfPromises)

Comment: I was assuming native support, but q is good.  I think you can tell Mongoose that you're using that, too, as in `mongoose.Promise = require('q').Promise;`